# How to write a query that will efficiently handle large amount of records?

Tags: java, sql

Suppose I have a Table X that has a billion records.

```
Table X

ProductID AccountID ContractID
```

`ProductID` and `AccountID` make a composite key for Table X.

Now, in memory, I have a map (let's say Java HashMap) that contains a million (ProductID, AccountID) pairs.

I want to create a file that will contain all the (ProductID, AccountID) as well as the corresponding ContractID for that pair.

Now I can use a for loop and for each (ProductID, AccountID) I can query the table, but then I would have to do this a million times and it would be really inefficient.

The question is, how to write a query that will do this efficiently? Or can such a query be written at all? Is there another way out?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @mortb , the question is meant to be independent of the database I am using.

Comment: Query back all three columns for every row, then for each entry in the result set find the corresponding entry in your HashMap and assign its `ContractID`. Once you've done that for all of them, write to the file. Possibly not the most efficient method, but should be faster than doing a million queries against your DB.

Comment: It seems that you need to get almost all this table. In this case, don't try to restrict the data with a too complex query, just do something like `select ProductID AccountID ContractID from X' Then, for each line, find the corresponding entry in your map.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, ya that's possible, but it uses up a lot of memory.

Comment: Where do you use a lot of memory? You just iterate on the result of your request and write lines one by one in your result file (with a `BuffuredReader`). The additional memory is negligeable compared to the size of your map.

Comment: @adenoyelle You are reading the entire table of billion rows into memory. That would be pretty huge.

Comment: @CodeBlue: Not if you are iterating through the ResultSet row-by-row; the tuples you have already processed are ready for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact SQL dialect, I'd perform an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT ProductID, AccountID, ContractID
FROM X
INNER JOIN MemTable m ON m.ProductID = X.ProductID AND m.AccountID = X.AccountID
```

---

You now added `Java` as a tag, so am I right in thinking that the map is within your Java application? If so, it will get tough - you may actually need to query the database a million times.

On the other hand you could construct a string containing one single, large SQL statement like that:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE ProductID IN (...) AND AccountID IN (...)
```

where your loop just fills in a list of product IDs and account IDs comma separated. Then you issue that command once. The command should for example look like this, assuming both IDs are numeric:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE ProductID IN (1,2,3,4) AND AccountID IN (99,88,77)
```

**EDIT**
Please note that my last suggestion may have the following flaw (you'll have to decide whether this is actually a problem for you):

Assume your map contains (1, 99) and (3, 77), but in table `X` there are additional records (1, 77) and (3, 99). The result of my query will be (1,99), (3, 77), (1, 77) and (3, 99) as both IDs are not treated as an "entity", but individually.

So as long as there are rows that contain any combination of the given ProductID and AccountID, they will be returned.

Assuming the DB system you're using allows for this, you could expand the `SELECT` statement into something like this:

```
SELECT ProductID, AccountID, ContractID FROM X WHERE ProductID = <ValueFromMap> AND AccountID = <ValueFromMap>
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductID, AccountID, ContractID FROM X WHERE ...
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion, but this assumes that I have those records in MemTable. I don't have them in a table in the database. They're in memory.

Comment: Hmmm, the IN is what I was thinking of as well. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Also, is there a restriction on the size of a SQL query? Could I really have a query that contains a million product IDs?

Comment: :) Thanks for this detailed answer. Very helpful, especially the "flaw" that you mentioned with the IN clause.

Comment: In some DBMS you can use `WHERE (ProductID,AccountID) IN ((1,99), (3,77), (5,48), ...)`

Comment: @CodeBlue If you try to put a million values in an IN I'd expect you to run into problems. I recall having issues using an Oracle database, at the very least; I don't remember the exact number it complained about but I think it was 1000.

Answer (score 2):

If speed and efficiency are of importance, then a query with a million "unions" or a million items in an IN clause is not going to be acceptable.

A more performant solution would be to perform a bulk insert of your ProductID/AccountID hashmap into a temp table, let's call it #temp.  I'm not going to describe the bulk insert because that is database dependent.  Then you can perform a simple join query:

```
SELECT ProductID, AccountID, ContractID
FROM X
INNER JOIN #temp t ON t.ProductID = X.ProductID AND t.AccountID = X.AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your memory map is in your Java program? If so I think there is no efficient solution that will be database independent. Best I can think of is to try and find continous id-ranges in your memory map so that you can write SELECT FROM X where ID >= xx AND id <= yy and avoid selecting duplicate ids.